# C# - Drag and Drop & Keep Control: Extension

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

sorry to bother again with a similar question. However, I have an issue with my code again in C#. I would like to give you the code I have got so far:

```
    private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox flower2 = new PictureBox();
        flower2.Image = Properties.Resources.Flower3;
        flower2.Location = new Point(panel1.Location.X + 10, panel1.Location.Y + 10);
        flower2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(pictureBox2.Size.Width, pictureBox2.Size.Height);
        flower2.Parent = panel1;
        this.Controls.Add(flower2);

        flower2.BringToFront();
        flower2.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(flower2_MouseMove);
        flower2.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(flower2_MouseDown);
    }

    private void flower2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
        }
    }

    private void flower2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            flower2.Left = e.X + flower2.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
            flower2.Top = e.Y + flower2.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
        }
    }
```

What I wanted it to do is when an image is clicked, create a new one and be able to drag and drop it. I succeeded only when I put my code at the top of the page. Which is not what I want because I want to be able to add as many images as I would like. I tried alot of different methods. The errors are at:

```
      flower2.Left = e.X + flower2.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
      flower2.Top = e.Y + flower2.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
```

At all the words under the name of flower2. This is because, I have defined flower2 in pictureBox2_Click so everytime it's clicked a new PictureBox will generate. But, I need to make it so I can generate as many images as I want and without putting it at the top of the page, this makes it so it only uses one image at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each picturebox you make is routed to those events, thus the `sender` object is the picturebox, you just need to cast it to the right type then move that.

```
 PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
 pb.Left = e.X + pb.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
```

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks so much! It even fixed my transparency issue in the background of my pictureBoxes! Thanks so much!